# A Bochner's theorem for matrix-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, measure-theory

A known result in the literature, generally referred to (as to my knowledge) as Bochner's theorem, states that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is positive definite (i.e. the matrix $\{f(t_j-t_l)\}_{j,l=1,\dots,n}$ is positive definite) if and only if it is the characteristic function (or Fourier transform) of a finite Borel measure $\mu$, i.e.
$$
f(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}tx}\mu(\mathrm{d}x).
$$

Is there a generalization of the theorem to *matrix-valued* (or even operator-valued) positive definite functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$? In that case, I would expect such functions to be characteristic functions of some matrix-valued measure $\mu$.